# JavaFX - Positioning image with character input

Tags: java, javafx

I have a GUI that takes the input of an image name, and once the refresh button is pressed, its displayed in a fixed position. I want to be able to input a character 'A-G' which will change the X position of the image, and a character '0-6' that will change the Y position of the image. The name of the images are just "A1", "A2"..."A5". So, if the user inputs "A1B3", it will display the image A1 in X-Position 'B' and Y-Position '3'. So B could be 200, and 3 could be 300, which makes the (X,Y) coordinates (200,300).

This is my code that gets the users input for the image.

```
private void getImage(){
    Image img = new Image("comp1110/ass2/gui/assets/" + textField.getText() + ".png", 100, 100, false, false);

    ImageView image = new ImageView();
    image.setImage(img);
    image.setX(100);
    image.setY(100);
    pane.getChildren().add(image);
}
```

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: How to read the 2nd and 3rd character from the users input and make the image translate according to the users input.

Comment: Why the 2nd and 3rd character from their input?

Comment: 'A1' is the name of the Image, 'B' is the 2nd character that the user inputs that determines the X-Coordinate of the image, '3' is the 3rd character that the user inputs that determines the Y-coordinate of the character. The 2nd character is from A-G, and the 3rd character is from '0-6'. So another combination a user can input i 'A1C5'. I don't know how to approach this and wanted some guidance, not asking for all the code. Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with the [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,int%29) method?

Comment: Just a suggestion but you should avoid jamming all the information together and possibly confusing the user by making them name an image with the same values as coordinates

Comment: @VGR would that work with characters?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do something along the lines of this yes there is some cosmetic issues that you will need to fix. But its only to give you an idea of what to do. It uses a gridpane so you don't have to worry about getting exact coordinates I choose a vbox so I didn't have to worry about layout you can keep the Pane that you have it shouldn't make a difference.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private GridPane gridPane;
    private TextField imageTextField = new TextField();
    private HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        fillHashMapValues();

        gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            RowConstraints rowConstraints = new RowConstraints();
            rowConstraints.setPercentHeight(14);
            gridPane.getRowConstraints().add(rowConstraints);

            ColumnConstraints columnConstraints = new ColumnConstraints();
            columnConstraints.setPercentWidth(14);
            gridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(columnConstraints);

            gridPane.addColumn(i);
            gridPane.addRow(i);
        }

        imageTextField.setPromptText("Enter Image Letters?");

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setPromptText("Enter Coordinates");

        Button button = new Button("Go!");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            addToGridPane(textField.getText());
        });

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setPrefSize(300, 300);
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(imageTextField, textField, button, gridPane);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
        primaryStage.show();
        button.requestFocus();//This is only so you can see the prompt text its irrelevant
    }

    private void fillHashMapValues(){
        hashMap.put("A", "1");
        hashMap.put("B", "2");
        hashMap.put("C", "3");
        hashMap.put("D", "4");
        hashMap.put("E", "5");
        hashMap.put("F", "6");
        hashMap.put("G", "7");
    }

    private void addToGridPane(String string){
        char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
        if(chars.length==2){//Do more data validation here
            if(hashMap.containsKey(String.valueOf(chars[0]))) {
                int xValue = Integer.parseInt(hashMap.get(String.valueOf(chars[0])));
                int yValue = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(chars[1]));

                ImageView image = getImage();

                gridPane.add(image, xValue, yValue);
            }
        }
    }

    private ImageView getImage(){
        Image image = new Image("comp1110/ass2/gui/assets/" + imageTextField.getText() + ".png", 100, 100, false, false);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setImage(image);
        //imageView.setX(100);
        //imageView.setY(100);
        //pane.getChildren().add(image);
        return imageView;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```